# Empty page displaying when trying to search something on google chrome on my Android SDK Emulator

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-emulator

I have installed Google Chrome(latest One) on my Android SDK emulator, it got installed successfully but I'm getting blank page when I am trying to search anything.

Comment: I daresay that what's worng with webkit on your emulator.